# Why can facet_wrap() in ggplot2 be expressed with either a tilde (~) or vars()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet

A tilde (`~`) in R generally denotes an anonymous function or formula, if I understand correctly. In `ggplot2`, you can use `facet_wrap()` to split your plot into facets based on a factor variable with multiple levels. There are two different ways to express this, and they both produce similar results:

```
# load starwars and tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
data(starwars)
```

With a `~`:

```
ggplot(data = starwars, mapping = aes(x = mass)) + 
   geom_histogram(fill = "blue", alpha = .2) + 
   theme_minimal() + 
   facet_wrap( ~ gender, nrow = 1)
```

With `vars()`:

```
ggplot(data = starwars, mapping = aes(x = mass)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "blue", alpha = .2) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  facet_wrap( vars(gender), nrow = 1)
```

How are `vars()` and `~` equivalent in `ggplot2`? How is `~` being used in a manner that is analogous, or equivalent to, its typical usage as an anonymous function or formula in R? It doesn't seem like it's a function here? Can someone help clarify how `vars()` and `~` for `facet_wrap()` denote the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two plots should be identical.

In `ggplot2`, `vars()` is just a quoting function that takes inputs to be evaluated, which in this case is the variable name used to form the faceting groups. In other words, the column you supplied, usually a variable with more than one level, will be automatically quoted, then evaluated in the context of the data to form small panels of plots. I recommend using `vars()` inputs when you want to create a function to wrap *around* `facet_wrap()`; it’s a lot easier.

The `~`, on the other hand, is syntax specific to the `facet_wrap()` function. For example, `facet_wrap(~ variable_name`) does not imply the estimation of some formulaic expression. Rather, as a one-sided formula with a variable on the right-hand side, it’s like telling R to feed the function the variable in its current form, which is just the name of the column itself. It’s confusing because we usually use the `~` to denote a relationship between x and y. It’s kind of the same thing in this context. The missing dependent y variable to the left of the `~` represents the row values, whereas the independent x variable to the right of the `~` represents the column(s). Note, the function may already know the y variable, which is usually specified inside of the `aes()` call. Layering on `facet_wrap(~ ...)` is just a quick way to partition those y values (rows) across each dimension (level) of your x variable.

Comment: Very clearly explained! Thank you